# java component - searching for words in char

Tags: java, function, components

is there any **Java function** or pre-made **component** which allows us to pass - plain text (char) and it would search for a WORD ?

example: we have a MySQL DB and a field in a table called "Subject"

if that email arrives and the subject says - "I wish I had some yellow mustard"

we could use that function to scan that Subject for a keyword

** we are looking

txs pros

Comment: It is not a dupe - This is asking for any known - Component / Function which can take INPUT as text/char and VAR as "word" and return YES or NO if that text contains that VAR

Answer (score 1):

```
if (someString.contains(someOtherString)) {

}
```